# How to fix 'GLib-GObject-WARNING / CRITICAL'

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gtk

i'm writing some code in Qt, and when I use QColorDialog there is a freeze of the application with the following output:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:53:36.573: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:53:36.573: cannot add class private field to invalid type '<invalid>'

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:53:36.573: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:53:36.573: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:53:36.573: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:53:36.573: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:53:36.573: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:53:36.573: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:53:36.573: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:53:36.573: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'
```

I tried the same code in a blank project and it works. I'm using this code to display the QColorDialog:

```
QColor m_color;
m_color = QColorDialog::getColor(m_color, this, QString(), QColorDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
```

I've already tried to clean QtCreator cache deleting /home/user/.config/QtProject and I've already tried to delete .pro.user file in the project

I've tried to run on both Debian 9 and Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon, same problem.

Comment: Something—possibly a plugin somewhere in either Qt or QtCreator—is trying to unload GTK and re-load it, which is explicitly unsupported.

Comment: I agree. Try without the QColorDialog::DontUseNativeDialog flag. That might avoid any ignorance in Qt's clobbering of the native Gtk.

Comment: Without the DontUseNativeDialog flag I've the same problems.